# Comaprision of FDD and TDD on the basis of Throughput

Tags: networking, computer-science, network-protocols, wireless

I have studied Frequency division duplex (FDD) and Time division duplex (TDD) but i can't find its difference on the basis of throughput. Is there any person who have an adequate knowledge about it. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

There is no throughput difference between the two methods.
If you have a 100Mbps link and you split it to 10 equal users, both FDM and TDM will give each user a 10Mbps link.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many free variables in your question to give a specific answer. In FDD paired frequencies are used to accomplish simultaneous upload and download. In TDD, the same frequency is used for both upload and download and by adjusting timeslots used for upload and download, their ratio can be adjusted dynamically based on how much data there is to be sent or received.